# How can you access the fields of a lookup of a lookup of a lookup?

Tags: apex, lightning, lookup

So lets say objectA has a lookup of objectB which has a lookup of objectc 
Is there anyway of doing:

objectA.lookUpToB__r.lookupToC__r.fieldOfC__c ? 
or anything similar?

Im trying to avoid querying a map of B and C if possible.

objectA.lookupToB__c works just fine.

However, accessing a lookup inside of B To C doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and `lookUpToB__r.lookupToC__r.fieldOfC__c` is exactly what you would need to add to your query for object A

Something like

```
[SELECT Id, lookUpToB__r.lookupToC__r.fieldOfC__c
FROM ObjectA
WHERE Field__c = value]
```

You can do this up to 5 levels (`B__r.C__r.D__r.E__r.F__r.FieldOnF__c`), or down one level (a nested select, `(SELECT Id, Field__c FROM ChildObjects__r)`)

The key, though, is that you can't just pull related data out of thin air. You need to include the data you want from related objects in a query. Records in trigger context variables (`trigger.new` and the like) also do not have any data from related objects in them (i.e. you need to query for related data, even in a trigger)

You also need to include the full path from the "Base" object (the one specified in the `FROM` clause) to the piece of related data *for every field on a related object that you want to get data for*.

Yes, that is quite tedious
...but queries are typically the governor limit you run into first when trying to scale code.